# Why react native admob not working in RN v0.60.4?

Tags: react-native, admob

I am trying include admob in react native, when I install react-native-admob and write all configuration necessary it´s not working and appears the next message:

Try npm install @types/react-native-admob if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing declare module 'react-native-admob';

I tried install with this @types/react-native-admob but not work, then I tried the second option, I created the file index.d.ts with:

```
declare module 'react-native-admob'

export {as AdMobBanner} from './RNAdMobBanner'
```

But not work.

I used the documentacion of [Library and example](https://github.com/sbugert/react-native-admob)

How can I include react-native-admob?

Comment: Hi, I've fixed your formatting. Please read [ask] and then [edit] your question. Be more specific, "not work" isn't a helpful problem description.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I will try to improve, I'm new on this platform

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please read the full documentation.
To install it on your project run this: `npm i --save react-native-admob@next`. This will install you the last version of react-native-admob.
After that you need to link it: `react-native link react-native-admob`.

You will find the npm package [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-admob)